# "phantom" modifications on binary files immediately after checkout

Tags: windows, git, atlassian-sourcetree

This situation is a little complicated, so I apologize in advance. I've done everything I can think of and researched all I can find but still can't quite figure this one out.

I work on a repo that has a large number of files with windows-style line endings. At some point some of the files were changed to linux-style. I suspect I did this inadvertently via cygwin and/or vim, but the initial cause isn't actually all that important.

The problem is that some legacy applications I support require files to have `CRLF` line-endings. Rather than actually attempt to change the line ending on every text file in the repo, I tried a quick solution that did not work as expected. I tried putting a `.gitattributes` file in the root of the repo with `* text eol=crlf`, since my understanding was that it was force all files to be `CRLF`.

What I didn't understand at that time was that this relied on git determining which files were text and which were binary. This seems to have caused a situation where a number of false positives are being reported. Files are listed as modified when no changes have actually been made.

After a fair amount of research into the guts of `.gitattributes` and line-endings and all that, I came up with a new `.gitattributes` file. This one specifically lists the required `CRLF` files and also a number of files that should be treated as binary.

Unfortunately, I'm still getting phantom modifications on a few remaining files. What's strange is that all of these file extensions were explicitly marked as binary in `.gitattributes`. For example, in my `.gitattributes` (which I paste below) I have the line `*.exe binary` but even with that line I have several `.exe` files which show as modified.

Further adding to the mystery, if I check out the "modified" files, the changes go away and everything is fine. I might be tempted to call this a suitable workaround but as far as I can tell there is no way to check out an individual file in the git client most of the team is using: Sourcetree. I found a workaround where you right click the file, view log, and reset to a specific commit, but it does not have the same effect as checking out the file.

As an extra clue, in Sourcetree it's easy to open the before/after versions of files. I opened the "before" version of one of the `.exe`s and it just opened with no problems. The "after" version prompted me to choose an application to open it with. This leads me to believe that the `.exe` has become corrupt through a process I don't understand.

The "changed" files are two `.exe`s, a `.tgz`, and a `.pm` file. Interestingly, the .pm file somehow changed a *single* CRLF line to LF

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to resolve this with a more specific `.gitattributes` file and ultimately need a solution git newbies can use.

Thanks!

My `.gitattributes` file:

```
*.Object text eol=crlf
*.CS text eol=crlf
*.Script text eol=crlf
*.Project text eol=crlf
*.actions text eol=crlf

*.pm binary

*.png binary
*.PNG binary

*.jpg binary
*.JPG binary
*.jpeg binary
*.JPEG binary

*.dll binary
*.DLL binary

*.exe binary
*.EXE binary

*.tgz binary
*.TGZ binary

*.doc binary
*.DOC binary
```

My core git config:

```
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
symlinks = false
ignorecase = true
```

**tl;dr**: On a windows system with the `.gitattributes` file listed above, git is indicating certain files are modified immediately after checkout. This applies to several filetypes that are explicitly listed as binary. On CLI git, checking out the file fixes it. Sourcetree does not seem to have a similar option. How can I get these files to abide by the `.gitattributes` rules?